# How do I respond with a "syn ack" packet when receiving a "syn" packet through a raw socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am curious about raw sockets and and how to create them and would like to implement my own TCP mechanism. I have read some examples and have succeeded with sending both custom made TCP packets and UDP packets with my own written IP header (of course influenced by a lot of examples). I have checked with Wireshark that the packet is reaching its destination, so everything is fine so far.

But regarding TCP packets, to make the full handshake:

```
Client     Server
syn  ---> 
     <---  syn ack 
ack  --->
```

What do I need from the server´s point of view to get the `syn` packet so I can send the `syn ack` back to the client?

Comment: "What do I need from the server´s point of view to get the syn packet" what do you mean by this?

Comment: When the syn packet has reached the server on the specified port, how can I catch the packet within the application running on the server?

Comment: since you're handling the IP by yourself , network protocol will pass frame to your IP layer, you take out the `message` from IP's payload, your `message` contains the syn header now I guess.

Comment: Yes, but I need to get the packet someway into my program on the server. That´s what I don´t know how to do. Since I have declared the socket on the client with `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0)` I think I shall do the same on the server program to send back a `syn ack` packet through a raw socket. But how can I fetch the `syn` packet in my server application?

Comment: TCP/IP is documented in an RFC and various online articles like on wikipedia describe it in even more detail, have you bothered looking at them?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Of course I have. I know exactly how TCP works and have done it for a long time. What I don´t know is how to, with C/C++ code, fetch a TCP packet with the `syn` flag enabled.

Comment: ...and that does not RFC or Wikipedia say anything about.

Comment: @Rox: You're implementing TCP.  You're _using_ UDP.  UDP doesn't have a `syn` flag.  You'll have to send the flags as part of the data of the UDP packet.

Comment: Wait, are you using UDP, or are you using raw?  They're different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive packets on a raw socket, just call `recv` or `recvfrom` on it.  The OS will return you a copy of the next packet addressed to the machine, with headers and all, which should include address info.  Watch the destination address, port, and transport protocol, and ignore any that aren't what you were expecting. (Since the point of a raw socket is that there's no built-in notion of ports or anything the OS could use to route packets to sockets, it doesn't know what program to send it to...so every raw socket should receive every packet addressed to the machine.  Meaning you might receive lots of crap you have no interest in.)

Once you see a packet addressed to "you", just build a SYN/ACK packet and send it to the address and port listed as the source in the received packet.

Note, though: the OS will often do its own processing of TCP and UDP packets (including sending ICMP "port unreachable" or other responses for ports it doesn't have listeners for)...and doing your own processing on top of that is bound to cause wackiness.  If you're going to implement your own flavor of TCP, you might want to use a different protocol number.  (Of course, then most clients won't be able to connect to it...you'd have to make a client as well.)

Comment: UDP has sockets, so you don't have to worry about the destination address, port, and transport protocol if you're listening for UDP.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If you have a UDP socket, you don't have to worry -- the OS will filter them for you, and only give you UDP messages addressed to the address:port bound to the socket.  A raw socket, on the other hand, is rather dumb -- the OS passes you everything and puts it on you to recognize (and thus parse) the stuff you care about.

Comment: I had interpreted the original post as implementing TCP on UDP "have succeeded with sending [...] UDP packets with my own written IP header..." But upon review, he _also_ says "I am curious about raw sockets and and how to create them and would like to implement my own TCP mechanism.", so I'm not sure what he's using.